# error: ‘virtual bool wxTopLevelWindowGTK::Show(bool)’ is inaccessible

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile wxWidgets first example command-line, And getting following error

```
/usr/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/gtk/toplevel.h: In member function ‘virtual bool MyApp::OnInit()’:
/usr/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/gtk/toplevel.h:63:18: error: ‘virtual bool wxTopLevelWindowGTK::Show(bool)’ is inaccessible
     virtual bool Show(bool show = true);
                  ^
app1.cpp:36:19: error: within this context
   frame->Show(true);
                   ^
app1.cpp:36:19: error: ‘wxTopLevelWindowGTK’ is not an accessible base of ‘MyFrame’
```

I am using command line to compile program

```
g++ -v `wx-config --version=3.0 --cxxflags` -std=c++11 `wx-config --version=3.0 --libs` app1.cpp
```

and getting following error log : [Error Log](http://pastebin.com/zA7kFj7c)

Complete Code: [Source Code](http://pastebin.com/P4UgMKpz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class MyFrame : wxFrame
```

should be

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
```

By default class inheritence is private. In the error message ‘wxTopLevelWindowGTK’ is not an accessible base of ‘MyFrame’ is a pretty good description of what has gone wrong.